# Can Django be prevented from truncating long table names?

Tags: django, oracle

I'm using Django with an existing Oracle DB (i.e., one where the tables were NOT created by Django). So in my models I am having to indicate the table name by specifying a value for db_table in the Meta class. I'm running into problems becuase the tables I wish to access belong to a different user than the one I have credentials for. I am authorized to view the tables (no trouble doing it in SQL Developer).

When the name of an Oracle table would otherwise be over 30 bytes, Django chops off the last four bytes of the name and replaces them with a repeatable 4-byte hash of the rest of the table’s name. This is all well and good for tables Django makes itself. It also normally wouldn’t be a problem for accessing tables in existing DBs (as in my case) since Oracle itself would’ve constrained the names to 30 bytes.

The problem is that Django doesn’t have a separate facility for noting that the table belongs to another user. So I'm using a dot-syntax workaround (by just setting db_table as, e.g. “USERNAME.MY_29_BYTE_TABLE_NAMEXXXXXXXX”), but since this leads to the **overall** table name exceeding 30 bytes, Django does its truncation trick and tries to query against a table name that doesn’t exist.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior, or a different way to specify the user separate from the name of the table?

Comment: This sounds like it might be a legitimate bug in django!, you should see if there is anything related in https://code.djangoproject.com/query and add a new ticket if not.

Comment: Consider a LOGIN trigger that does and ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA rather than specifying the owner for each table

Comment: Excellent suggestions, both. If I'm understanding correctly, Gary's idea will only work if all the tables you wish to access belong to the same user. Though that is the case for me, for other situations the solution suggested by SuperDuper below might be more useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Truncate is caused at Oracle Django DB backend by [quote_name](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py#L235) method, which follows SQL92 requirements and uses hard-coded value [max_name_length](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py#L224).

You can override this behavior by creating custom DB backend or by monkeypatch like this:

```
from django.db.backends.oracle.base import DatabaseOperations
DatabaseOperations.max_name_length = lambda s: <NEW_MAX_VALUE>
```

It's not really clear why you need more than 30 characters in table name, as it violates [Oracle Schema Object Naming Rules](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm#sthref723).

Comment: This tells me how to prevent the behavior. Thanks! Actually, I am not specifying a table name of >30 characters, Django just thinks I am because of the extra bytes needed to indicate the user. I suppose this solution would not be so viable in situations where you have a mix of Django-generated tables (i.e., that use the default APPNAME_MODLENAME naming convention) and pre-existing tables in Oracle, because if you raise this value Django really might try to create tables with overly long names. But I suppose you can control that by always specifying db_table in such cases.