# Django Bug with long name in db_column?

Tags: python, django, django-models

When i use a long name in db_columns at a field in Models.py, django does not work correct. It truncates the name, and add random letters/numbers at the end.

Like this:  db_column='my_loooooooooooooooooong_column_name'

And when i try queryset, django returns:
'table name'.'my_looooooooooooooo6E4': invalid identifier.

**My scenario in detail**:

I have a legacy database in Oracle.
**The table name in database**: PALAVRA_CHAVE_ENTREGA_VALOR

**With 3 Fields**: PCEV_CD_PALAVRA_CHAVE_ENTREGA_VALOR (*Primary Key*), PACH_CD_PALAVRA_CHAVE, ENVA_CD_ENTREGA_VALOR

In my **models.py**:

```
class PalavraChaveEntregaValor(models.Model):
    pcev_cd_palavra_chave_entrega_valor = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='pcev_cd_palavra_chave_entrega_valor')
    pach_cd_palavra_chave = models.BigIntegerField()
    enva_cd_entrega_valor = models.BigIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'palavra_chave_entrega_valor'
```

When i run in shell (**python manage.py shell**) this command:
`PalavraChaveEntregaValor.objects.all()` 
I got output: **DatabaseError: ORA-00904: "PALAVRA_CHAVE_ENTREGA_VALOR"."PCEV_CD_PALAVRA_CHAVE_ENTRA6E4": invalid identifier**

I made a test, changed the long name **PCEV_CD_PALAVRA_CHAVE_ENTREGA_VALOR** to **PCEV_CD**, and everthing works fine..

Is there a limitation of characters in db_columns at django? Is there a workaround for this? If not, i will have to create a lot of Views in Oracle Database with shorter names of columns only for django work.. Change the current table column names is not an option.

Comment: Could https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949550/can-django-be-prevented-from-truncating-long-table-names be helpful at all? It looks like the length restriction may be in the Django Oracle backend, and you could potentially work around it.

Comment: Wow,it worked! In Models.py i set: from django.db.backends.oracle.base import DatabaseOperations
DatabaseOperations.max_name_length = lambda s: <NEW_MAX_VALUE>

Comment: Glad that helped!

Comment: @bouteillebleu, thanks!! I'm searching for this like two days.. Please, make as an answer for i accept as solution